# How to implement Lollipop activity transitions with views

Tags: android, android-activity, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

I have a custom view, that I replace with different view. Part of the elements on the new view are connected. Like the user image.

I want to use the same animation effect as in [Lollipop activities transition](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RhiPJByIMrM&index=8&list=WL) between my views.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You should use either Scene class or use any of the Animators.

Comment: Just use the `Transition` framework that was introduced in API 19?

Comment: If your custom View is a ViewGroup that behaves normally, the Transition framework should work just fine (ChangeBounds, Fade, etc). If your custom View draws the UI specially, then those special parts won't work well with the Transition framework. If you can contain the special drawing in separate Views, contained in a ViewGroup (could be custom), the Transition Framework should be able to handle that.